# Webmail direct access restriction

Tags: php, redirect, webmail

My website i newly added a section employee email log in , while clicking on that it redirect the page to web-mail log in page

```
<table><tr><td>
<a href="mysite.com/webmail">Employee Mail</a>
</td></tr></table>
```

Now restrict the direct access  mysite.com/webmail,page can open only through this link

Comment: Uhm, why? What difference does it make whether the site is accessed by clicking on a particular link or typing the address into the address bar?

Comment: nothing.. just need to block the direct access, and to use the website.. thts all

Comment: This is a stupid requirement. Sorry, but there's no other way to put it.

Comment: @deceze Don't judge the requirement without background knowledge. There might always be a good reason, we're just unaware of (though highly unlikely in this case).

Comment: The answer is probably that you need a proper login system, but unless you explain why you want to do this, nobody can help

Comment: @aefxx Whatever problem they're trying to solve here, this is most certainly not the way to do it. As you say, *highly* unlikely that there's any good reason for this. More likely an insufficient understanding of the actual problem.

Comment: @deceze I'm all with you on this. IMHO the OP is tasked with a problem that's way over his current skill-set.

Comment: @aefxx ...or someone with an insufficient skill set has tasked the OP with this... ;)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are hosting the site on an Apache HTTP Server with `mod_rewrite` enabled, you could try to grant access based on the user's referer.

```
# In your .htaccess
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://mysite\.com/access-page [NC]
RewriteRule ^webmail - [L]
```

This would stop everybody from visiting the link `mysite.com/webmail` if their referer doesn't match the URL `http://mysite\.com/access-page`.

Comment: ...and it will also stop you from ever going back to the site from anywhere else. I.e., you *always* have to go through `/access-page`. No back button, no clicking on "Home" to get back to `/webmail`...

Comment: Yep, that's what I figured from the OP's question. No more, no less.

Comment: tried this.. but not working.. while clicking on the links its opening the webmail page and also the direct access

Comment: while clicking on the link i need to open the webpage in an iframe, but direct access cant allow.. just need to hide the url from users. thats all

Comment: Uhm, wait a second!?! Now, you want an `iframe` that hides the URL. Sorry, dude, ask again once you figured out what exactely you are trying to achieve. I'm out.

Comment: my requirement is just want to block the direct access,just want to get the web mail through only that page.. if thats not possible i think about i frame , that may be my mistake

Comment: @user3572808 That's exactely what the rewrite code above does. It limits access to users that bare the `access-page` referer URL. You went ahead and changed the referer URL to suit your setup, didn't you?

Comment: yes done, but after i add that code. while am trying to type directly on the browser mysite.com/webmail its redirect to webmail login page.. i need to block that, thts the requirement

Comment: Ups, my bad. I forgot to negate the `RewriteCond` (a `!` was missing).